# How redux action dispatch differ between class & function component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I would like to know how redux implementation in functional component different from class component.

Because I got a working example and not working example.

The working example is the class component. When I use class component and use `props.fetchSomething`
Its always works.

here is the class component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Posts extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  }

  render() {
    let postItems = this.props.posts.map((post) => (
      <div key={post.id}>
        <h3>{post.title}</h3>
        <p>{post.body}</p>
      </div>
    ));

    return <div>{postItems}</div>;
  }
}
```

Now I will show you the not working version of function component.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Posts = ({ fetchPosts, posts }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  let items = posts.map((post) => {
    <div key={post.id}>
      <h3>{post.title}</h3>
      <p>{post.body}</p>
    </div>;
  });

  return <div>{items}</div>;
};
```

As you can see, `FROM MY UNDERSTANDING` these 2 works the same, Because i fetch the data at mounting state and map the store data.

Here my rest of the code. which are  redux operations. I used these below codes for both class and function component. The thing is, only the class component show the list of data. The function component always return an empty array.

**WHY IS THAT**

```
Posts.propTypes = {
  fetchPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  newPost: PropTypes.object,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  // coming from root reducer
  posts: state.posts.itemsArray,
  newPost: state.posts.item,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(Posts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Items is not assigned to anything because the callback function passed to map doesn't return anything:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchPosts();
  //you should really try using create-react app, then
  //  you'd see the missing dependency when compiling
  //  When you also set up vs code you'd see it when you
  //  open the file in the editor
}, [fetchPosts]);
//in VS code you would have a linter warning:
//  Expected to return a value in arrow function.
//  also defined items as const
const items = posts.map((post) => (//replaced { with (
  <div key={post.id}>
    <h3>{post.title}</h3>
    <p>{post.body}</p>
  </div>//removed ;
)/**replaced } with ) */);
```

If you use `{...}` after the arrow of an arrow function then `...` is the body of the function and you have to **return** something from this body:

```
let items = posts.map((post) => {
  return (//have to return jsx
    <div key={post.id}>
      <h3>{post.title}</h3>
      <p>{post.body}</p>
    </div>
  ); //removed ;
});
```

You can also have an arrow function that has no body, then whatever comes after the arrow is the return value. For example: `const add = (a,b)=>a+b`.

If you have a bodyless arrow function that returns an object it gets confusing because an object and a function body have the same syntax `{}` so to return an object you can do `({})`, here is an example: `const add = (a,b)=>({sumAB:a+b})`. With jsx the `(<jsx />)` are optional so `const hello = () => <div>hello</div>;` and `const hello = () => (<div>hello</div>);` are both valid. When multi line jsx is returned a formatter such as prettier will usually format it with `(<jsx />)` like so:

```
const hello = () => (
  <div>
    <div>hello</div>
  </div>
);
```